# SQLAlchemy Insert w/ Dictionary

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

For this situation assume there is a table declared with the declarative base called Game, with column names "espn_game_id" and "a_name".  There is a session object open under the variable "s".  So this works:

```
s.add(Game(espn_game_id=888, a_name='lol'))
s.commit()
```

This fails:

```
n = {"espn_game_id": 888, "a_name": 'lol'}
s.add(Game(n))
s.commit()
```

This works (assuming there is already an entry with espn_game_id==888):

```
n = {"a_name": 'lol'}
s.query(Game).filter(Game.espn_game_id==888).update(n)
s.commit()
```

Why does the second case fail and is there a way to get that type of syntax to work here?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try to replace:

```
s.add(Game(n))
```

with:

```
s.add(Game(**n))
```

Let's assume you have function like this:

```
def foo(**kwargs):
    print [item for item in kwargs.items()]
```

It expects keyword not positional arguments so this will work:

```
foo(**{'foo': 1, 'bar': 2})
```

and this will fail:

```
foo({'foo': 1, 'bar': 2})
```

For a better explanation you should read [*args and **kwargs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/args-and-kwargs)